# How to get parameters via $batch method CHANGESET_PROCESS?

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, sap-gateway

I would usually get Function Import parameters from IT_PARAMETER in ~EXECUTE_ACTION, however if I'm coming in via $batch and therefore hitting ~CHANGESET_PROCESS, how do I get the import parameters?

There's nothing I can see in it_changeset_request to get me these parameters.  They aren't keys, so I can't get the keys, nor are they filters.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the type of the table, it is a a table of type ty_s_changeset_request in /IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_TYPES. There, you can access entry_provider \ request_headers \ request_context and other attributes.